# Why is HttpTestingController no longer receiving requests?

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have a slew of Angular unit tests for functions that do http requests.  The error that seems to be happening is that my `HttpTestingController` is no longer receiving any http requests.

Example unit test:

```js
it('should successfully change password', (done) => {
  passwordService.updateUserPassword(testUsers.username, testUsers.password).subscribe((response) => {
    expect(response).toMatchObject({ success: true });
    done();
  });

  // Error is happening on the next line
  const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${authMock.endpoint}/public/user`);
  expect(req.request.method).toBe('PATCH');
  req.flush({});
});
```

Example function:

```js
updateUserPassword(username: string, password: string): Observable<{ success: boolean }> {
  const body = { username, password };
  return this.http.patch(this.endpoint, body, this.authService.httpOptions).pipe(
    map(() => ({ success: true }))
  );
}
```

This was all working before and this lines up with all tutorials and documentation I've found while researching this issue.
All that has changed since it last worked is I updated Jest from version 27.x to 28.x.  I checked migration guides and I can't find anything there that could have broken this.